# removing leading and trailing single quotation marks from a string

Tags: sql, replace

I need to figure out the SQL command to remove leading and trailing single quotation marks, but if there are apostrophe's in the string, I do not want to remove them (ex: `'isn't'`, I want to be isn't`).

I am not a code writer, so this is a little more difficult for me. I think I could use:

```
UPDATE table1 SET notes = REPLACE(notes, '\'', '');
```

But that would remove all and not leave any apostrophes in place, I believe. So just how do I remove the single quotation at the beginning of the string and the end of the string?

I appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a naive check of the first and last characters. For MYSQL you could do:

```
UPDATE table1 SET notes = SUBSTRING(notes, 
                 CASE WHEN LEFT(notes, 1) = '''' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, 
                 LENGTH(notes) - CASE WHEN LEFT(notes, 1) = '''' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
                             - CASE WHEN RIGHT(notes, 1) = '''' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not a coder, I can cut and paste a command in phpMyAdmin, but that is about my limit

Comment: I've updated the code to be relevant to your table, and work with mysql. 
Ps. at one point, none of us were coders. Dive in!

Comment: Thanks for you help.       I ended up doing this UPDATE ibf_ccs_custom_database_10 SET field_125 = REPLACE(field_125, '\'', '&#39;') We were having a problem losing all data in a field when trying to edit if that field included single quotation marks. I am not sure why, but when you clicked to edit the record, the fields were totally blank. Sooo, in the long run I just replaced the ' with &#39 and that worked

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a database I can test on right now but something along this line should work:

```
UPDATE table1 SET notes = replace(trim(REPLACE(notes, '/'', '          ')),'          ','/'');
```

How it works:

Replace all single quotes with ten spaces (realistically you will not have an instance of ten spaces in the column right?) then trim the result then replace every instance of ten spaces back to a single quote.

Because I don't know what database you are using you will need to play around with the syntax and you may have to use a combination of ltrim and rtrim as "Trim" is not available on every db package. Trim is a simple command that simply removes starting and ending spaces from a string.

Of course it goes without saying test this on a temp table before you do so on a live table.

Comment: UPDATE table one SET quotes = replace(trim(REPLACE(quotes, ''', '          ')),'          ',''')
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table one SET quotes = replace(trim(REPLACE(quotes, ''', '          ')),'       ' at line 1

Comment: When replacing a single quote in MySQL you need /' instead of just '. Updated original post. Hence my comment that you would need to check the Syntax as you didn't indicate what DB you were using

Comment: Sorry,  I ended up doing this     UPDATE ibf_ccs_custom_database_10 SET field_125 = REPLACE(field_125, '\'', '&#39;')    We were having a problem losing all data in a field when trying to edit and that field included single quotation marks.  I am not sure why, but when you clicked to edit the record, the fields were totally blank.  Sooo, in the long run I just replaced the ' with &#39 and that worked.

Answer (score -1):

Dirty but working way:

> create table stest (id serial,test text);
>
> insert into stest (test) values ('isn''t');
> insert into stest (test) values ('''isn''t');
>
> insert into stest (test) values ('''isn''t''');
>
> insert into stest (test) values ('isn''t''');
>
> insert into stest (test) values ('isn''t'' ''isn''t');
>
> select * from stest;

id │     test
────┼───────────────

1 │ isn't

2 │ 'isn't

3 │ 'isn't'

4 │ isn't'

5 │ isn't' 'isn't

(5 rows)

with first as (select id,regexp_replace(test,'^''','') as t from stest),
second as (select id,regexp_replace(t,'''$','') as t from first),
third as (select id,regexp_replace(t,''' ',' ') as t from second),
fourth as ( select id,regexp_replace(t,' ''',' ') as t from third)
update stest s  set test=t from fourth f where s.id=f.id;

> select * from stest;
> id │    test

────┼─────────────

1 │ isn't

2 │ isn't

3 │ isn't

4 │ isn't

5 │ isn't isn't

(5 rows)

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not a coder, I can cut and paste a command in phpMyAdmin, but that is about my limit